# IntelliJ settings partially imported

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to share with my team the settings of IntelliJ Idea 2023 using manual Export/Import. The zip file is properly generated but there are several configurations not present: Git, Build Tools -> Maven, Compiler and others. Only the Code Style and other minor configs seem exported. Is this how the export works or am I missing something?
If I am understanding properly the documenation, these settings should be included. I have tried it with different instances of IntelliJ without success.

Comment: There are two types of settings - global and project ones (they have mark in the IDE settings). Export settings exports only "global" settings. You may try "Settings Repository". Also there is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309002/Make-Settings-Sync-new-separate-feature-suitable-for-team-settings-sharing

Comment: Thank you for your answer @y.bedrov I think JetBrains should defenitely work on this